# Can you use numpy's fromfile to store files in an ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, io

I'm still pretty new to python. I've been able to write a program that will read in a file from binary and stores the data that's there in a few arrays. Now that I've been able to complete a few other tasks with this program, I'm trying to go back through all my code and see where I can make it more efficient, learning Python better along the way. In particular, I'm trying to update the reading and storing of data from the file. Using `numpy`'s `fromfile` is MUCH, MUCH faster at unpacking data than the `struct.unpack` method, and works wonderfully for a 1D array structure. However, I have some of the data stored in 2D arrays. I am seemingly stuck on how to implement the same type of storing in the 2D array. Does anyone have any ideas or hints as to how I may be able to perform this?

My basic program structure is as follows:

```
from numpy import fromfile
import numpy as np


file = open(theFilePath,'rb')

####### File Header #########

reservedParse = 4
fileHeaderBytes = 4 + int(131072/reservedParse)  #Parsing out the bins in the file header
fileHeaderArray = np.zeros(fileHeaderBytes)
fileHeaderArray[0] = fromfile(file, dtype='<I', count=1) #File Index; 4 Bytes
fileHeaderArray[1] = fromfile(file, dtype='<I', count=1) #The Number of Packets; 4 bytes
fileHeaderArray[2] = fromfile(file, dtype='<Q', count=1) #Timestamp; 16 bytes; 2, 8-byte.
fileHeaderArray[3] = fromfile(file, dtype='<Q', count=1)
fileHeaderArray[4:] = fromfile(file, dtype='<I', count=int(131072/reservedParse)) #Empty header space

####### Data Packets #########
#Note: Each packet begins with a header containing information about the data stream followed by the data.

packets = int(fileHeaderArray[1])  #The number of packets in the data stream
dataLength = int(28672)

packHeader = np.zeros(14*packets).reshape((packets,14))
data       = np.zeros(dataLength*packets).reshape((packets,dataLength))


for i in range(packets):
    packHeader[i][0] = fromfile(file, dtype='>H', count=1)  #Model Num
    packHeader[i][1] = fromfile(file, dtype='>H', count=1)  #Packet ID
    packHeader[i][2] = fromfile(file, dtype='>I', count=1)  #Coarse Timestamp
    ....#Continuing on
    packHeader[i][13] = fromfile(file, dtype='>i', count=1) #4 bytes of reserved space
    data[i] = fromfile(file, dtype='<h', count=dataLength) #Actual data
```

Essentially this is what I have right now. Is there a way I can do this without doing the loop? Going through that loop does not seem particularly fast or numpy-ish.

For reference, the for-loop structure using `unpack` and not `numpy` is:

```
packHeader = [[0 for x in range(14)] for y in range(packets)]
data = [[0 for x in range(dataLength)] for y in range(packets)]

for i in range(packets):
    packHeader[i][0] = unpack('>H', file.read(2))  #Model Num
    packHeader[i][1] = unpack('>H', file.read(2))  #Packet ID
    packHeader[i][2] = unpack('>I', file.read(4))  #Coarse Timestamp
    ....#Continuing on
    packHeader[i][13] = unpack('>i', file.read(4)) #4 bytes of reserved space
    packHeader[i]=list(chain(*packHeader[i]))   #Deals with the tuple issue ((x,),(y,),...) -> (x,y,...)

    data[i] = [unpack('<h', file.read(2))  for j in range(dataLength)] #Actual data 
    data[i] = list(chain(*data[i])) #Deals with the tuple issue ((x,),(y,),...) -> (x,y,...)
```

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Another option is to use numpy.save and numpy.load, to write .npy files.